# Live Agent REST API: AgentDisconnect usage

Tags: apex, rest-api, liveagent, apexrest

According [official guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_AgentDisconnect.htm), "**AgentDisconnect**" just has explanation as follow:

**Indicates that the agent has been disconnected from the chat.**

but I don't know how to utilize it. can someone give me more explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AgentDisconnect** isn't a resource, it's type of message in [Messages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_Messages_responses_overview.htm) body response:

*The Messages request returns an array of objects that represent all the events that occurred during an agent’s chat with a chat customer.
This request can return several subtypes with unique response bodies, depending on the events that occurred within the chat.*

You should listen liveagent events at `https://hostname/chat/rest/System/Messages`

AgentDisconnect type example:

```
{
    "messages": [{
        "type": "AgentDisconnect",
        "message": {}
    }],
    "sequence": 2
}
```

e.g. ChatEstablished type:

```
{
    "messages": [{
        "type": "ChatEstablished",
        "message": {
            "chasitorIdleTimeout": {
                "isEnabled": false
            },
            "sneakPeekEnabled": true,
            "name": "ilya l",
            "userId": "00536000000FT8P"
        }
    }],
    "sequence": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could update the user with a user-friendly message to indicate the operator disconnected. Bear in mind, this API is meant to be used when you are implementing Live Agent from scratch so statuses like this help you provide the correct information back in the UI.

Comment: Hi @PepeFloyd, thank your explanation. can you tell me how to utilize it like, "AgentDisconnect" is a restful URL request or respond?